# Removing namespace from nodes and after that copy that node into new node using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xml-namespaces

I have xml which is having namespace so i want

1. Remove namespace
   2)After removing namespace copy that node under different node, here is my code

can someone tell me how to achieve both in single xsl. after above code i am getting only removed name space.
I have seen many article but have not find something related to that.
Input :

```
<UWInitial xmlns:d3p1="http:someUrl">
<d3p1:string>ABC</d3p1:string>
<d3p1:string>EFG</d3p1:string>
<d3p1:string>EHG</d3p1:string>
<d3p1:string>EFD</d3p1:string>
<d3p1:string>ESF</d3p1:string>
</UWInitial>
'''

output what i want :

'''
<UWInitial>
<NewNode>
   <string>ABC</string>
</NewNode>
<NewNode>
   <string>EFG</string>
</NewNode>
<NewNode>
   <string>EHG</string>
</NewNode>
<NewNode>
   <string>EFD</string>
</NewNode>
<NewNode>
   <string>ESF</string>
</NewNode>
</UWInitial>
'''

XSLT that i use:

'''
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:d3p1="someUrl">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

     <xsl:template match="d3p1:string" >

        <xsl:element name="NewNode">
                      <xsl:copy>                  
                        <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()"/>
                      </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:element>
        
    </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:call-template name="Test" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*" >
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="comment() | text() | processing-instruction()" >
            <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
'''


output which i get:
'''
<UWInitial>
<string>ABC</string>
<string>EFG</string>
<string>EHG</string>
<string>EFD</string>
<string>ESF</string>
</UWInitial>
'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to wrap any string into a NewNode use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:d3p1="http:someUrl"
    exclude-result-prefixes="d3p1"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="d3p1:string">
      <NewNode>
          <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
              <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </xsl:element>
      </NewNode>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Martin, I have run this and getting same output. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<UWInitial>
   <string>ABC</string>
  <string>EFG</string>
  <string>EHG</string>
  <string>EFD</string>
  <string>ESF</string>
</UWInitial>  But what i want iis <string > node should come under <NewNode>.

Comment: I get the NewNode as a wrapper for string at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxNakAz.